# Rails 5 app on HEROKU crashes with any error in code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I am developing a Rails 5 app on a local computer. And serve it using rails s which starts a Puma server in single mode. Of course I test my app locally but sometime there is still an error somewhere that I didn't detect.

In this case I had an error in a function that I don't use at the moment so the app works without any problem because the code with the error is not being executed.

Now, when I deploy this to my Heroku server the app crashes immediately without any messages. Heroku just says:

```
Went from started to crashed
```

Why does this happen? I didn't even execute the part with the error...why does the entire app need to crash?

How can I debug this?

Right now there is no way of fixing this but undoing step by step until the last deploy.

Did the same happen to someone of you? What can I do?

Comment: it's probably related to environment variables or database settings more than the error. Check the logs on Heroku!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, the reason your app is crashing in production while it is not crashing in development is that, in `config\environments\development` you have:

```
config.eager_load = false
```

Whereas in `config\environments\production` you have:

```
config.eager_load = true
```

So, in development, your failing code just quietly sits there causing no problems (because it is not eager loaded). But, in production, your app is crashing because your failing code gets eagerly loaded and makes your app sad.

Personally, I have been setting:

```
config.eager_load = true
```

In my development environment - because I got sick of thinking all was good only to find that I had critical errors when pushing to Heroku.

Comment: Changed my settings, too.